# Loopback4 File upload Storage component Example

Tags: file, upload, components, storage, loopback

I’m looking for an example for a file store using loopback4, could someone provide the controller configuration for file crud operations?

Answer (score 3):

LoopBack 4 does not provide a built-in parser for multipart file upload requests. Instead, we provide extension points allowing applications to use a 3rd party parsers like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

There are two options how to write a controller accepting file uploads. You can learn more about this topic in our docs, see [Parsing requests](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Parsing-requests.html) and [Extending request body parsing](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Extending-request-body-parsing.html)

**1. Handle file uploads in the controller method**

Instruct LoopBack to pass the raw body stream to your controller method. In the controller method, call the file-upload parser to process the multi-part stream.

Benefits: different endpoints may want to process the uploaded files differently. By implementing file-upload parsing in a controller method, it's easy to customize all aspects of this process.

Cross-posting an example from [file-upload.acceptance.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/0151a3d560c262097aa798d0ef7ad4d7fce4eebf/packages/rest/src/__tests__/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload.acceptance.ts):

```js
import * as multer from 'multer';

class FileUploadController {
  @post('/show-body', {
    responses: {
      // (left out for brevity)
    },
  })
  async showBody(
    @requestBody({
      description: 'multipart/form-data value.',
      required: true,
      content: {
        'multipart/form-data': {
          // Skip body parsing
          'x-parser': 'stream',
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    })
    request: Request,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response,
  ): Promise<Object> {
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    const upload = multer({storage});
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      upload.any()(request, response, err => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else {
          resolve({
            files: request.files,
            fields: (request as any).fields,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**2. Implement & register a body parser for multi-part file uploads**

In this option, all file-uploads are processed at transport layer in the same way for all controller methods. Controller methods receive parsed data.

Example body parser implementation from [file-upload-with-parser.acceptance.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/0151a3d560c262097aa798d0ef7ad4d7fce4eebf/packages/rest/src/__tests__/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload-with-parser.acceptance.ts):

```js
class MultipartFormDataBodyParser implements BodyParser {
  name = 'multipart/form-data';

  supports(mediaType: string) {
    // The mediaType can be
    // `multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------979177593423179356726653`
    return mediaType.startsWith('multipart/form-data');
  }

  async parse(request: Request): Promise<RequestBody> {
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    const upload = multer({storage});
    return new Promise<RequestBody>((resolve, reject) => {
      upload.any()(request, {} as any, err => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else {
          resolve({
            value: {
              files: request.files,
              fields: (request as any).fields,
            },
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

An example controller leveraging this body parser:

```js
class FileUploadController {
  @post('/show-body', {
    responses: {
      // (left out for brevity)
    },
  })
  async showBody(
    @requestBody({
      description: 'multipart/form-data value.',
      required: true,
      content: {
        'multipart/form-data': {
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    })
    {files, fields}: any,
  ) {
    return body;
  }
}
```